# multiple Go modules in a monorepo and custom dir structure

Tags: go, go-modules

I have 2 possibly related issues.

I have a test monorepo setup, with 2 subdirectories (`mod1` and `mod2`).
Each one of them has a `go.mod` file in them, and each of the modules has a single `.go` file with basic printing code. in `mod2` there is a subdirectory `mod2_lib` (that holds one of those simple `.go` files with basic printing code), since I read that Go modules are basically their own little `GOPATH`'s.

[image]

Id like to call function `Run()` thats in a package `mod2/mod2_lib` from `mod1`, but all Im getting is `build github.com/account_name/test/mod1: cannot find module for path github.com/account_name/test/mod2/mod2_lib`.

here are the files Im using to figure this out:

mod1/t.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/account_name/test/mod2/mod2_lib"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("mod1")
    mod2_lib.Run()
}
```

mod2/mod2_lib/t_lib.go

```
package mod2_lib

import "fmt"

func Run() {
    fmt.Println("RUNS")
}
```

the second issue is that in this monorepo I'd like to have related Python and Rust code in top-level dirs `py` and `rust`. So I'd like to place all my Go packages in the `go/src` dir. How would other people import this `go/src` path into their project (possibly still having the `"github.com/account_name/test/mod2/mod2_lib"` as the import path, and not `"github.com/account_name/test/go/src/mod2/mod2_lib"`)?

can anyone give me some pointers on these issues? I want to move to using Golang modules, and abandon the `GOPATH`.

Comment: If the code is at `github.com/account_name/test/go/src/mod2/mod2_lib`, then that is the import path. That's how imports work. I'm not sure why the `src` part is in there, and it may cause you some issues (Go will detect it as a GOPATH). As to the compile error, have you done a `go get` or otherwise added `mod2` to the go.mod for `mod1`?

Comment: ok I'll definitely remove the `src` part. but Im dealing with that after I get the above described simple case (all modules/packages are in the root dir) working

Comment: @Adrian when I do a `go get` Im still getting `build github.com/account_name/test/mod1: cannot find module for path github.com/account_name/test/mod2/mod2_lib`

Comment: @Adrian question, with this setup if I make a change in `mod2` locally, without pushing it to github.com, `mod1` is not detecting that change locally and its still using the remote version. Any idea on how to handle this with this module structure (outside the `GOPATH`).

Comment: You can use `replace` to explicitly point at your local copy of the dependency: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem

Comment: if the local copy is not present (for people that are `get`/`build`-ing for the first time) will it still initially pull from github.com?

Comment: Not if the `replace` is in the `go.mod` committed to the repo, no. So you'll want to change it only locally, only for testing changes in the dependency.

Comment: thats what I thought. ok, I'll figure out how to best structure it. thanks @Adrian! much appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

the issue was that it was a private github.com repo. making it public fixed it! :) have to figure out authentication now for the module system.